# Trying to create a grid layout which has a column over multiple rows

Tags: html, css, grid

I'm trying to create a grid layout which has a column spanning over 2 rows.

This is as far as I've got [CodePen](http://codepen.io/pen/MKNjVK)

I would like `<div class="col-3">` to span over to the column underneath.

Could anyone give me a few pointers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

First of you must know about how grid layout works. Your method is wrong. Please check below url for grid ( sizing, layout and structure. )

http://getbootstrap.com/

Download or refer this frame work for column based html and layout.

Answer (score -1):

use flexBox for all the divs.
you don't need 'row' divs anymore.

use empty div for spacing and 'flex-grow' attribute for width multiplier.

checkout more in here -> https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/